# Sending file through socket goes wrong C

Tags: c, file, sockets

I'm on Windows. I try to send a file from client to server. It works when the server and client are on the same machine. But when I move the client to another machine, the server creates the desired file but fails to copy the client file. I don't understand why it works when server and client are on the same machine but when I move the client to another machine it doesn't.

How can I make my program work so that I can copy a file from client to server?

Server:

```
char ch[70];
printf("where do you want to save it(full path + name): ");
scanf_s("%s", ch, 70);

char c[70];
printf("which file you want to copy(full path + name): ");
scanf_s("%s", c, 70);

r = send(s, c, 70, 0); 
if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Client disconnected\n");
    break;
}

char buf[BUFSIZ];
size_t size = BUFSIZ;
                                        
FILE* copyFile;
fopen_s(&copyFile, ch, "wb");

while (size == BUFSIZ)
{
    recv(s, buf, BUFSIZ, 0);
    if (strncmp(buf, "exit", 10) == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    size = fwrite(buf, 1, BUFSIZ, copyFile);
}
fclose(copyFile);
```

Client:

```
char c[70];
res = recv(ClientSocket, c, 70, 0);
if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Server disconeccted\n");
    break;
}

char buf[BUFSIZ];
size_t size = BUFSIZ;

FILE* originalFile;
fopen_s(&originalFile, c, "rb");

while (size == BUFSIZ)
{
    size = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZ, originalFile);
    send(ClientSocket, buf, BUFSIZ, 0);
}
send(ClientSocket, "exit", 10, 0);
fclose(originalFile);
```

Comment: There are numerous problems revolving around transfer sizes and error checking, but the code fragments presented don't appear to contain information bearing directly on the question posed.  Please present a [mre].

Comment: `recv()` doesn't add a null terminator, you can't use `strcmp()` to process it.

Comment: `send(ClientSocket, "exit", 10, 0);` `"exit"` is only 5 bytes, why are you sending 10?

Comment: What if the file contains `exit` in it?

Comment: You should use `send(clientSocket, buf, size, 0);` in case the buffer doesn't contain `size` bytes.

Comment: Are you using TCP or UDP? TCP doesn't maintain message boundaries, so there's no guarantee that each `recv()` will get `BUFSIZE` bytes.

Comment: If I can't use strncmp(), how should I then break out of the while loop when copying is done?

Comment: If you aren't looking at the values returned by `send()` and `recv()` to see how many bytes were *actually* sent or received by that call, then you're guaranteed to have problems sending larger amounts of data.  Either of those commands can and sometimes will send/receive fewer bytes than you asked it to, and when that happens it is up to your code to notice and do the right thing, rather than carry blindly on as if all of the bytes had been sent/received.

Comment: send and recv return the number of bytes sent or received successfully. What should I do with the return values?

Comment: Umm.. add them up until you have transferred the required number of bytes.